# Display Spring MVC model attributes in thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing a full Spring application with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf in view layer. In the past I've worked with JSPs and Spring MVC in view layer, but those are now dinosaurs I guess.
So my problem is that with JSPs I could very easily display model attributes in view by adding value in model.addAttribute in controller and displaying the same in JSP anywhere with placeholder evaluating to springex `${value}`. So if I want to place a title in page I can write `<title>${appName}<title>`. This is one of the places where I can put any springex.

I am having hard time to figure out how to do this with Thymeleaf as it uses attribute based parsers. So anywhere on page if thymeleaf prefix is not included it won't process spring expression. It's very hard to work with limited set of tag libraries. I've heard of custom attributes for thymeleaf but I guess there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `th:text` attribute, e.g.

```
<html ... xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    ...
    <title th:text="${appName}">mocking text</title>
    ...
</html>
```

The content of the tag ("mocking text" in this case) gets replaced by the result of the expression in the `th:text` attribute.

Of course you need to have the appropriate JAR files on CLASSPATH and have the Thymeleaf view resolver properly configured, as described in the [Thymeleaf+Spring guide](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html).

For additional information about how template processing works with Thymeleaf in general you can refer to the [Thymeleaf guide](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html).